# Не видит файл в python

Tags: python-3.x

У меня программа лежит вместе с фотографией в одной директории, но он не видит фотографию.

```
import base64

imag =open("lol.jpeg", 'rb')# открываем файл на чтение в двойчном формате(rb)
image_read = imag.read()
image_64_encode = base64.b64decode(image_read)

print(image_64_encode)
```

Ошибка:

> can't open file '': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory

Comment: Я уже и с .text проверял ваше не видит(

Comment: Я не просто так пишу я уже перепробовал все известные методы

Comment: Дико извиняюсь не о том подумалXD

Comment: Как запускается скрипт?

Comment: PyCharm использую

Comment: Благодарю я встал на путь истенный

Comment: В настройках проекта (меню Файл) есть "директория для выполнения" или как-то так. Думаю, что файл ищется в ней и нужно её поменять.

Answer (score 0):

```
import base64

imag =open("/lol.jpeg", 'rb')
image_read = imag.read()
image_64_encode = base64.b64decode(image_read)

print(image_64_encode)
```